# Using UWP API with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, uwp

In `Visual Studio` I included: `using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;` and it works. When adding/including namespaces in `Qt` I get errors. Any documentation how to use `UWP API` with `Qt`?

**For example:**

```
.h
#include <windows.devices.enumeration.h>

.cpp
DeviceAccessInformation deviceInfo;
```

I get error: `C2065: 'DeviceAccessInformation': undeclared identifier`

**Update:**

I have found some information related the issue. So I have added the `Win SDK` path (`INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0"`) to the `.pro` file. Also added the `#include "winrt/windows.devices.enumeration.h"` to the header file but it still can't find the `DeviceAccessInformation deviceInfo;`, throws error: `C2065: DeviceAccessInformation: undeclared identifier`.

Also I have checked the samples, and add the namespace.
`using namespace winrt;`

and it displays the error: `C2871: 'winrt': a namespace with this name does not exist`

Also I have noticed the warning: `-1: warning: winrt_manifest_install.path is not defined: install target not created`

I have included the `WindowsApp` library but the issue still exists.

```
contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64) {
    LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.16299.0/um/x64" -lWindowsApp
} else {
    LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.16299.0/um/x86" -lWindowsApp
}
```

I think the problem is with the wrong includes or I missing something.

**Update 2:**

Can anyone confirm that `Qt 5.9.3 UWP x32/x64` kits work with `UWP API`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: #include <windows.devices.enumeration.h>, Where have you seen this type of import used?

Comment: @eyllanesc

It's just a test. So how to include it right? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert on windows, but that include does not meet the standard of import of C ++.

Comment: @eyllanesc

Yes, I agree but it found the header file. When adding the `using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;` it throws error: `C2039: 'Devices': is not a member of 'Windows'`. `UWP API` reference contains only namespaces.

Comment: You need Qt built for UWP. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms-and-configurations.html

Comment: @AlexanderVX

I have the Qt UWP kits installed and I can create empty `UWP` app. So I think the problem is with the wrong includes.

Comment: The problem is then likely with symbols needed to allow blocks of #ifdefs in those headers. As long as Visual Studio builds same project (?) there must be a local change enabling the symbol e.g. #define SYMBOL or /DSYMBOL.

Comment: @AlexanderVX

Ok. I will check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to develop native `UWP` app using `Visual Studio` even though I fixed the issue by installing `Qt` extension for `VS` and switching `Win SDK` kit to 16299.