# Qt5 - Windows : inconsistent dll linkage error and definition of dllimport static data member not allowed

Tags: c++, windows, qt, c++11, qt5

I am trying to build a project using `Windows 10` and `Qt5.12`. The small program is using the `smtp` protocol available [here](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt). I can confirm that on my `Windows` I have the `OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019`.
On my `Ubuntu 19.04` the same exact program compiles and run as usual but not on `Windows`.

I am attaching below a print screen of the errors; however those are mostly of two types:

**1)** `inconsistent dll linkage`

**2)** `definition of dllimport static data member not allowed`

[image: errors]

Following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995323/using-uwp-api-with-qt) it seems that `Windows` needs its "own" include (i.e. `#include <windows....`) however in my case the `smtp` library from the above link does not have any `#include <windows>` and don't know if they have to be generated. It seems they don't from the post I found

In addition I was reading [this post too](https://forum.qt.io/topic/62935/error-while-building-winrt-x64-application-with-qt5-5-1/5) because I thought I could be useful but no information was useful to help me sort out the problem

I dug more and actually went to where the `windows includes` are and the following is the path I was able to find, but don't know if that could be useful:

[image: includes]

From all the posts I red the problem seems to be, in this specific case for `Windows` on how the 
`.pro` file is written. Below my `.pro` file.
Note that I cloned this repository into my `windows 10`.

**.pro**

```
QT += quick quickcontrols2 concurrent network core gui

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

TARGET = SMTPEmail
TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += SMTP_BUILD
win32:CONFIG += dll


# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        progressbardialog.cpp \
        robot.cpp \
        robotmanager.cpp \
        settings/emailaddress.cpp \
        settings/mimeattachment.cpp \
        settings/mimecontentformatter.cpp \
        settings/mimefile.cpp \
        settings/mimehtml.cpp \
        settings/mimeinlinefile.cpp \
        settings/mimemessage.cpp \
        settings/mimemultipart.cpp \
        settings/mimepart.cpp \
        settings/mimetext.cpp \
        settings/quotedprintable.cpp \
        settings/smtpclient.cpp \
        user.cpp \
        usermanager.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

HEADERS += \
    progressbardialog.h \
    robot.h \
    robotmanager.h \
    settings/SmtpMime \
    settings/emailaddress.h \
    settings/mimeattachment.h \
    settings/mimecontentformatter.h \
    settings/mimefile.h \
    settings/mimehtml.h \
    settings/mimeinlinefile.h \
    settings/mimemessage.h \
    settings/mimemultipart.h \
    settings/mimepart.h \
    settings/mimetext.h \
    settings/quotedprintable.h \
    settings/smtpclient.h \
    settings/smtpexports.h \
    user.h \
    usermanager.h
```

**EDITS**

To be even more specific it seems that every header the offending line is the following below:

```
class SMTP_EXPORT EmailAddress : public QObject // <-- SMTP_EXPORT
```

which leads to the **smtpexports.h** which I copied below:

```
#ifndef SMTPEXPORTS_H
#define SMTPEXPORTS_H

#ifdef SMTP_BUILD
#define SMTP_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#define SMTP_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // SMTPEXPORTS_H
```

**ADDITIONAL EDITS**

Almost all error are solved after adding `DEFINES += SMTP_BUILD` but I have two errors left and I added a print screen below:

[image: error]

Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction on how to solve this problem.

Comment: did you define `SMTP_BUILD` when you build the lib?

Comment: @Thomas, thank you very much for reading the question. I am not a `Windows` user as I mainly use `Ubuntu`. So I guess the answer is no. How do I do that? I only `git clone` the folder and try to run it.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt/commit/a4f4235139635bb375152950e6d852b4bbb38868) indicates that maybe you did.

Comment: or maybe it doesn't. it lookes like you are not going through the lib but added the source files. then you prob. need to add the `DEFINES += SMTP_BUILD` line to your `.pro` file.

Comment: as done [here](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt/blob/v1.1/SMTPEmail.pro)

Comment: I followed your advice and got rid of almost all the errors. I only have left two errors. I updated the question adding **ADDITIONAL EDITS**. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: I also updated the code I posted on the question with the modifications

Comment: i think you need to ask a new question. feel free to accept my answer. I'm not sure that the `win32:CONFIG += dll` is right for your usecase.

Comment: Thank you I just asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59271296/qt5-windows-windows-cannot-find-executable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are designed to be compiled with the define `SMTP_BUILD` set where the source is added, either to a library or to an executable. You have to add the

```
DEFINES += SMTP_BUILD
```

to your `pro` file.