# Qt5 - Windows :Windows cannot find executable

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, qt5, qt-creator

I am trying to build a project using `Windows 10` and `Qt5.12`. The small program is using the `smtp` protocol available [here](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt). I can confirm that on my Windows I have the OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019. On my Ubuntu 19.04 the same exact program compiles and run as usual but not on Windows.

I `git clone` my repository into `Windows`, followed successfully [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256699/qt5-windows-inconsistent-dll-linkage-error-and-definition-of-dllimport-stati) and the program builds correctly.

**The problem** is that when I run it, it `cannot find the executable` and is asking for it as it is possible to see from the print screen below:

[image: executable]

here is my `.pro` file:

```
QT += quick quickcontrols2 concurrent network core gui

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

TARGET = SMTPEmail
DEFINES += SMTP_BUILD

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        progressbardialog.cpp \
        robot.cpp \
        robotmanager.cpp \
        settings/emailaddress.cpp \
        settings/mimeattachment.cpp \
        settings/mimecontentformatter.cpp \
        settings/mimefile.cpp \
        settings/mimehtml.cpp \
        settings/mimeinlinefile.cpp \
        settings/mimemessage.cpp \
        settings/mimemultipart.cpp \
        settings/mimepart.cpp \
        settings/mimetext.cpp \
        settings/quotedprintable.cpp \
        settings/smtpclient.cpp \
        user.cpp \
        usermanager.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

HEADERS += \
    progressbardialog.h \
    robot.h \
    robotmanager.h \
    settings/SmtpMime \
    settings/emailaddress.h \
    settings/mimeattachment.h \
    settings/mimecontentformatter.h \
    settings/mimefile.h \
    settings/mimehtml.h \
    settings/mimeinlinefile.h \
    settings/mimemessage.h \
    settings/mimemultipart.h \
    settings/mimepart.h \
    settings/mimetext.h \
    settings/quotedprintable.h \
    settings/smtpclient.h \
    settings/smtpexports.h \
    user.h \
    usermanager.h
```

On my Desktop it is created automatically the `build` folder and thought that the executable would have been here. Below I Am also attaching a print screen of what is inside the `build` folder:

[image: desktop-folder]

Originally this project was deployed on `Ubuntu` and that gave me no problem. I `git clone` that repo into my `Windows`, added the missing `SMTP_BUILD` but I can't fine the executable that the window in the print screen is asking. What am I missing for this final step?

Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Check the debug/ subfolder

Comment: In the debug or release should be the executable. In QT-Creator click left on "Projects", what's the "build-directory"? If there's the correct Path, QT-Crator should find the executable.

Comment: the build directory is `C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\build-signalsQML-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug`

Comment: [this is the debug directory](https://i.imgur.com/DczPEhc.png) but I don't see any `.exe`

Comment: are you sure it linked successfully? Are you sure that you are building an executable?

Comment: @Emanuele change `TEMPLATE = lib` to `TEMPLATE = app`. Provide a real .pro

Comment: @Emanuele use my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the image of your .pro you are using `TEMPLATE = lib` whose objective is to create a library whose product is a .dll, .so, etc. that is not an .exe.

If you want to generate an executable you must use:

```
TEMPLATE = app
```

---

**Plus:**

To make it easier to include the library in your project, I have created [this project](https://github.com/eyllanesc/SmtpClient-for-Qt) whose objective is to provide a .pri that is easy to link to any project with .pro. To do this you must follow the following steps:

- Download the project
- Add `include(/path/of/SMTPEmail.pri)` to your .pro
- Includes using `#include <SmtpMime>`